# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using fragments, when I instantiate a fragment the first time it it. but the second time I got this exception. I couldn't find the line where I got the error?

```
 04-04 08:51:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29713): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-04 08:51:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29713): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    04-04 08:51:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29713):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3013)
    04-04 08:51:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29713):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:2902)
    04-04 08:51:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29713):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:2859)
    04-04 08:51:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29713):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:2839)
    04-04 08:51:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29713):    at android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout.wrap(Unknown Source)
    04-04 08:51:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29713):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Unknown Source)
    04-04 08:51:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29713):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Unknown Source)
    04-04 08:51:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29713):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(Unknown Source)
    04-04 08:51:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29713):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(Unknown Source)
    04-04 08:51:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29713):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    04-04 08:51:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29713):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    04-04 08:51:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29713):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    04-04 08:51:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29713):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
    04-04 08:51:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29713):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126)
    04-04 08:51:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29713):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-04 08:51:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29713):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
    04-04 08:51:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29713):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
    04-04 08:51:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29713):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
    04-04 08:51:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29713):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here are what i do when i click on an element of my list fragment.

```
// If we are not currently showing a fragment for the new
 // position, we need to create and install a new one.
 RouteSearchFragment df = RouteSearchFragment.newInstance(index);

 // Execute a transaction, replacing any existing fragment
 // with this one inside the frame.
 FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
 ft.replace(R.id.details_full, df);
 ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
 ft.commit();
```

The first time it is Ok, I click element2 from list, it's also ok; but when I return to element1 I got this bug.

Thanks every one!

Comment: need to call layoutView.removeAllViews(); before add views to layout

Comment: @imrankhan wrong! You can add without removing all. The most important part is missing and as there is no custom package in the stacktrace, I suggest you remove some code and test it step by step...

Comment: i add more details, please can you see that?

Comment: What's this RouteSearchFragment class?? Can't find any reference in Android docs. Please update the class definition too.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

When you override `OnCreateView` in your `RouteSearchFragment` class, do you have the

```
if(view != null) {
    return view; 
}
```

code segment?

If so, removing the return statement should solve your problem.

You can keep the code and return the view if you don't want to regenerate view data, and onDestroyView() method you remove this view from its parent like so:

```
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        if (view != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            if (parent != null) {
                parent.removeAllViews();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Override
 public void onDestroyView() {

  super.onDestroyView();

  ViewGroup parentViewGroup = (ViewGroup) mRoutesSearchViewContainer.getParent();

  if( null != parentViewGroup ) {

   parentViewGroup.removeView( mRoutesSearchViewContainer );
  }
  
 }

Comment: @Medo: Can you give brief explaination for this. I have the same error shown in the logcat. as you have given the suggestion "remove the return statement should solve your problem" but we need to return View object in onCreateView() method. can you provide snippet code for you're explanation. Thank you.

Comment: @Krishna Just inflate and return the view as you would normally. You can skip the whole if statement.

Comment: For me, I just had to replace `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container);` with `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);`

Answer (score 371):

Sorry to post to an old question but I was able to fix it using a totally different solution. I was getting this exception but I changed the first line of my onCreatView override from this:

```
View result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_layout, container);
```

...to this:

```
View result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_layout, container, false);
```

I have no idea why but using the override that accepts the boolean as the third param fixed it.  I think it tells the Fragment and/or Activity not to use the "container" as the parent of the newly-created View.

Comment: Don't be sorry - this was very useful to me, and clearly a number of other people. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I keep forgetting this and coming back to this answer

Comment: @Patrick, The first attaches the inflated view to the container, adding the false flag specifies you not want to add the inflated view to the container.

Comment: and I keep coming back to this post and finding out that this is THE ANSWER :)

Answer (score 45):

I have facing this issue many time.
Please add following code for resolve this issue :

```
@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        if (view != null) {
            ViewGroup parentViewGroup = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            if (parentViewGroup != null) {
                parentViewGroup.removeAllViews();
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you on this solution :) I have a very specific case where I can not use inflater to solve this. 

You saved me lots of time

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand cuz I'm new to android.

Comment: In view.getParent(); Where dose view object come from?

Comment: Cristy YG: Take a View instance as a global variable, and inflate your layout xml on above global variable. are you following me or not?

Comment: Yes, view instance declare as global.

Answer (score 35):

If you have this statement..

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container);//may be Incorrect
```

Then try this.. Add false as third argument.. May be it could help..

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);//correct one
```

Answer (score 22):

I had this code in a fragment and it was crashing if I try to come back to this fragment

```
if (mRootView == null) {
    mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
}
```

after gathering the answers on this thread, I realised that mRootView's parent still have mRootView as child. So, this was my fix.

```
if (mRootView == null) {
    mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
} else {
    ((ViewGroup) mRootView.getParent()).removeView(mRootView);
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: +1 helped me. Especially true if your activity stays but fragment manager is adding new fragments on top. when it gets back to the first fragment, need to make sure the old root view gets removed. Thanks!

Comment: It helped me a lot. I've been finding that solution for 3 days. Simple and pretty answer.

Comment: Wow! finally it worked for me!
grat solution. thanks!

Comment: I dont have a rationale why "(ViewGroup) mRootView.getParent()).removeView(mRootView);" works in contrast to directly calling " <WhateverIsParentViewGroupName>.removeView(mRootView)" But this works for me as well, I'm testing on Android 8.0 and 9.0. Thanks bud ^

Answer (score 16):

It also happens when the view returned by onCreateView() isn't the view that was inflated.

Example:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);

TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
textView.setText("Some text.");

return textView;
```

---

Fix:

```
return rootView;
```

Instead of:

```
return textView; // or whatever you returned
```

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem and couldn't solve it in Java code.  The problem was with my xml.

I was trying to add a textView to a container, but had wrapped the textView inside a LinearLayout.

This was the original xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now with the LinearLayout removed:

```html
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/>
```

This didn't seem like much to me but it did the trick, and I didn't change my Java code at all.  It was all in the xml.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding a `View` into a `layout`, but the View already is in another `layout`. A View can't be in more than one place.

Comment: i  added more details to my question, please can you see that?

Answer (score 1):

This solution can help :

```
public class FragmentItem extends Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
{
    View rootView;
    TextView textView;

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (rootView != null) 
        {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)rootView.Parent;
            parent.RemoveView(rootView);
        } else {
            rootView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.FragmentItem, container, false);
            textView = rootView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewDisplay);            
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think rootView will always be null since you didn't initialize it.

Comment: rootView always be null

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by setting `attachToRoot` of `inflater.inflate()` to `false`.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overview, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your xml file you should set layout_width and layout_height from wrap_content to match_parent. it's fixed for me.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to get these when adding a custom view to a FrameLayout. I did this:

```
if (this.chartFrame.indexOfChild(mark.markView) == -1)
                    this.chartFrame.addView(mark.markView);
```

Which checked to see if it was already in the layout.  Seemed to work until I saw an error today for the first time in years on API 31 (Android 12).  Not sure what is happening yet,