# Getting Java illegal state Exception when trying to add View by inflating xml

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, layout-inflater, illegalstateexception

Em getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Not able to find out which view has to be removed, any help would be really helpful.

Here is the Code snippet

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity Code

```
public class ToDo extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button addNew;
    RelativeLayout mainLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mainLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

        RelativeLayout rel;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        for(int idx=0;idx<2;idx++){
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            rel = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.data,null);
            params.setMargins(0, 50, 0, 0);

             TextView fromWeb= (TextView) rel.findViewById(R.id.txt);
             fromWeb.setText("AA");

             mainLayout.addView(rel,params);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007094/java-lang-illegalstateexception-the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is incorrect:

```
TextView fromWeb= (TextView) rel.findViewById(R.id.txt);
fromWeb.setText("AA");
rel.addView(fromWeb,params); // the TextView is alredy in the rel RelativeLayout!
mainLayout.addView(rel);
```

because you are adding **again**(with the `addView` method) the `TextView` which is already in the layout file(as you previously searched for it with `findViewById`). Instead it should be like this:

```
TextView fromWeb= (TextView) rel.findViewById(R.id.txt);
fromWeb.setText("AA");
mainLayout.addView(rel);
```

If you want margins for your `TextView` then set them in the layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: correct ! when i tried your edited code it is working, but the text is overlaping.even though i use params for relative Layout. check edited code

Comment: @Badrinath That is because you use a `RelativeLayout` in the `main.xml` file instead of a `LinearLayout` with `orientation` set to `vertical`.

Comment: I need to add multiple text Views one below the other so i used inflating mechanism.

Comment: After following the changes which u told it works like charm !

Answer (score 0):

verify your gradle version in gradlewrapper.properties and Project level build.gradle .
in my case

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
```

it works now