# Android View Pager and Chart Backgrounds

Tags: android, android-fragments, bitmap

I am currently working on an app that displays multiple charts on multiple fragments, which are viewed via a view pager.  When the charts are first drawn the background image is calculated and drawn to a bitmap image which is then drawn to the chart background.  At the moment this all works fine but after sliding through all of the fragments the background starts to disappear.

I would like to know if this a view pager issue using fragments and images or an android issue using bitmap, I know that is a difficult general question that is hard to answer but has anyone come across this before.  I am also looking at the invalidate method and the fact that are the initial draw maybe that is not being called on the re-swipe.  Any help, tips or pointers welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i always add a boolean to the onCreateView method, like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  if (!mInitialized) {
    mView = inflater.inflate(...);
    ...    
    mInitialized = true;
  }    
  return mView;
}
```

so you avoid re-initializing the fragments on each swipe. maybe this helps.

**EDIT:**

As DVN mentioned in the comments, if the following exception occurs

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

you can find some hints about it here: [java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007094/java-lang-illegalstateexception-the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent)

Comment: hey thanks for the tip, however I ran into another issue after implementing your code:  _java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first_

Comment: I added the following code to my fragment to fix that issue '@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        if (mView != null) {
            ViewGroup parentViewGroup = (ViewGroup) mView.getParent();
            if (parentViewGroup != null) {
                parentViewGroup.removeAllViews();
            }
        }
    }'  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007094/java-lang-illegalstateexception-the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent). For anyone who might need it.