# Dynamically adding views in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout, android-viewgroup

I am trying to add dynamic views into my layouts relative view. So the dynamic view which is to be added is another layout containing couple of editexts and other fields. Everything works perfectly but the only issue is whenever i add new views dynamically my previous contents are refreshed/cleared because i removeallviews before adding the layout. So I want some solution with which i should be able to add views without havinig to update my already added elements or without calling removeallviews before i add my new view.

Following below is my function which i am calling to add views

```
 private fun generatenewQuestionview() {
            val inflater =
                activity?.getApplicationContext()?.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater

            question1_layout.removeAllViews()



            for (i in 0 until viewmodel?.question1Array!!.size) {
 var layoutquestion1 = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.dynamic_question_layout, null);

                question1add = layoutquestion1.findViewById(R.id.add_more_btn_question1) as ImageView
                question1minus =
                    layoutquestion1.findViewById(R.id.minus_more_btn_question1) as ImageView
                question1key = layoutquestion1.findViewById(R.id.question1_et) as EditText


                if (i == 0) {
                    question1minus?.visibility = View.GONE
                } else {
                    question1minus?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }

                layoutquestion1.invalidate()

                question1_layout.addView(layoutquestion1)


                question1minus?.setOnClickListener()
                {
                    viewmodel?.question1Array!!.removeAt(0)
                    question1_layout.removeViewAt(i)
                    //generatenewQuestionview()
                }

                question1add?.setOnClickListener()
                {
                    generatenewQuestionview()
                    //viewmodel?.question1Array?.add(HashMap())
                    //generatenewQuestionview()
                    // question1_layout.addView(layoutquestion1)
                    //question1_layout.addView(layoutquestion1)
                    //addmorequestions()
                }
            }
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: so explain why are you using removeAllViews? just add new view!

Comment: if i add new view than it says your child already has parent

Comment: when defining new view set unique Id for each. also check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24819855/5750389